# MS Access VBA - Pulling a partial string from semi-consistent data in a field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've looked around but wasn't able to find an exact solution...

I have an identifier-type field that generally follows the format of XXX-YY-ZZZZZZZZ.  Sometimes the number of X's and Z's will vary, but the YY's are always enclosed between the two hyphens.  If I wanted to create another field using just the "YY", what would be the best function to use? There's also another reference table with the YYs listed that I intend to relate it to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to split the string into an array. Try this out

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim ExampleStr As String: ExampleStr = "XXX-YY-ZZZZZZZZ"
    Dim StrArray() As String

    StrArray = Split(ExampleStr, "-")

    Debug.Print StrArray(1) ' Return the second element
End Sub
```